# Can someone suggest a good workflow for working with WPF and PRISM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, workflow, unity-container, prism

I've worked with PRISM on one major project before so I'm pretty familiar with the concepts involved but I'm about to embark on a self managed project and was wondering if anyone has any pearls of wisdom about how to go about implementing an appropriate architecture for a straight forward LOB/Forms over data app. I'll want to leverage as much of PRISM and Unity as possible.

Obviously most people start with the bootstrapper, shell and regions but if you've got a reasonably simple but large app to build, with tight timescales ( like always :-) how I can I save some time in my workflow?  Where should I go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not much, but I started writing snippets to help with the bigger, repetitive parts of Prism, like creating a new command. Ideally you could have templates for adding a View or ViewModel and things like that also. I also have a quite decent ViewModelBase class and ViewController class for swopping out views in different regions. That way swopping a view comes down to a 1 liner most of the times.

Not much but it does save time.

I'd paste the snippet here but it doesnt format properly, suppose it is because it is XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Prism Command
      pcom
      
        Code snippet for creating a new Prism Command
      
      wilmarvh
    
    
      
        
          PublicPrism
          Name of the command ie. EditUserCommand
          ExampleAction
          string
        
        
          PrivatePrism
          Name of the command ie. editUserCommand
          exampleAction
          string

```
    public ICommand $PublicPrism$Command
    {
        get
        {
            if ($PrivatePrism$Command == null)
            {
                $PrivatePrism$Command = new DelegateCommand(Execute$PublicPrism$Command, CanExecute$PublicPrism$Command);
            }
            return $PrivatePrism$Command;
        }
    }

    public void Execute$PublicPrism$Command()
    {
        // do whatever here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private bool CanExecute$PublicPrism$Command()
    {
        // add executing criteria and checks here
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
```

$end$
]]>

Comment: It may not be much but it's the only answer so well done,..you get the points.